# How to show array elements one at a time using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I made a JavaScript array randomizer and it show the elements one at a time with interval. I want to make them show one at a time without the interval, but with button. When I click the button it shall switch to the next element, but until then it remains the same. Can you help me do that?

```js
var numberStrings = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"];

var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  document
    .getElementById('numberList')
    .innerHTML = numberStrings[i++];
  if (i == numberStrings.length) i = 0;
}, 2000);

function shuffleUsingRandomSwapping(array) {
  var j, x, i = 0,
    len = array.length;
  for (i; i < len; i++) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    x = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = x;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="shuffleUsingRandomSwapping(numberStrings);updateNumberList(numberStrings);">Shuffle Using Random Swapping</button>

<div id="numberList"></div>
```

Comment: what is the problem then? just delete that interval and move its function to your `updateNumberList` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var numberStrings = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"];

var curElement = 0;

function updateNumberList() {
  document
      .getElementById('numberList')
      .innerHTML = numberStrings[curElement++];
    if (curElement == numberStrings.length) curElement = 0;
}

function shuffleUsingRandomSwapping(array) {
  var j, x, i = 0,
    len = array.length;
  for (i; i < len; i++) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    x = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = x;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="shuffleUsingRandomSwapping(numberStrings);updateNumberList(numberStrings);">Shuffle Using Random Swapping</button>

<div id="numberList"></div>
```

I don't know you situation, but if you just want to display a random element from an array each time you press the button, it should be done in a much easier way, without shuffling the array.

```js
var numberStrings = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"];

function displayRandomElem() {
  document
      .getElementById('numberList')
      .innerHTML = numberStrings[Math.floor(Math.random() * numberStrings.length)];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayRandomElem()">Shuffle Using Random Swapping</button>

<div id="numberList"></div>
```

To show the values in random orders, so that they don't repeat themselves, use the next code:

```js
var numberStrings = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"];

function displayRandomElem() {
  if (numberStrings.length == 0) return;

  document
      .getElementById('numberList')
      .innerHTML = numberStrings.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * numberStrings.length), 1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayRandomElem()">Shuffle Using Random Swapping</button>

<div id="numberList"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to make them to not repeat themselves, until all are shown.

Comment: Do you want to show them in the order they appear in array, or random order?

Comment: in random order

Comment: Thank you so much!!